# Archive SharePoint list items with attachments to another site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, 2007, sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint list having more than 2,00000+ records. Its an email enabled list. I got a requirement to move items which are of DateModified > 60 to another list having the same template in another site collection.All the items are having attachments, so i couldn't find a way to batch insert items to the target list keeping attachments using ProcessBatchData method. I am currently iterating through the source items and inserting it in the target and it takes enough time to complete operation for some 5000 items. Could you please help if you know any better way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

If i was to move list elements and keep their version history etc. i would take a look at the homepage of Sharegate in order to download a trial so that You can evaluate it.

I have used it and i think it was very easy to use and the elements i moved/copied kept its properties.
The gui looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks Magnus. But I am looking for something with SharePoint server object model. I need to schedule this job after first round of archival which will move items whose datemodified > 60 days. Currently I have written a console application and planning to schedule this as windows job. The only problem I am facing is performance issues. I should have tried ProcesBatchData but my item has attachments, not sure how to implement this when item is having attachments.